# What does the sentence mean: How does he smell?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

> How does he smell?

Does that mean how the *he* will `smell other things` or how `himself smells`?

For example: If there is a dog who doesn't have a nose and a person asks the owner the above question.

Comment: It can mean either of those things. Which, depends entirely on the context of the conversation. Without context it is impossible to say. Hence the joke as mentioned by @Michael Harvey

Comment: The "How does he smell" joke could fairly be called the canonical bad joke, except that 'take my wife" seems to occupy that position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very old comedy routine, performed by two people.

> Person A: I say I say I say.
>
> Person B: What do you say?
>
> Person A: My dog's got no nose.
>
> Person B: No nose? How does he smell?
>
> Person A: Bloody awful!

The joke is based on two possible meanings of 'smell' - (1) be able to sense odours (2) have an odour. Person B means to ask "By what means is the dog able to sense the odours of things around himself?" Person A comedically misinterprets the question as "What is the quality or nature of the dog's own odour?"

Comment: The joke wouldn't work so well if you substitute (e.g.) 'grandfather' for 'dog', because dogs rely on their sense of smell much more than humans do.

Comment: If you substituted 'President' for 'dog', as with other things connected with him, it would not be funny at all.